# Java: Get attribute of subclass without casting

Tags: java, attributes, subclass, visitor-pattern

Let's say I have a superclass `Order` and two subclasses `VehicleOrder` and `TaskOrder`. Both inherrit a lot of methods from the superclass, but have one specific field: `VehicleOrder` has a `Model` and `TaskOrder` has a task.

Now, in an other class, I have a List of `Order`. In that method, I need to do calculations based on the order's specific field.

My solution for now is 'polluting' the superclass `Order` with two methods `getModel()` and `getTask()`, which return null by default and can be overriden by the subclasses. The other class then checks for null and if not null, makes the calculations. This doesn't feel like the right way to do this though...

As I don't know the subclass-types of the general list of orders in the other class, I can't cast to get the attribute.

The only other way to fix this is using the `Visitor pattern` , but that feels like a bit of overkill.. Is it?

Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: Visitor is a reasonable solution. It may also be possible to move the calculation onto VehicleOrder and TaskOrder. You may also want to keep two separate lists, rather than a List<Order>(). Polluting the superclass is functional, but brittle and undesirable.

Comment: From your other comments, `Visitor` seems a good solution.

Comment: Alright, thanks to both. I have thought about keeping two separate lists, but for that I would need to use Visitor to add the `Order`-object into the correct list, so that doesn't give me any gain. Moving the calculation doesn't work, as the different calculations need different parts of the computing class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract out a common base class (or interface) both Task and Model can implement. Let Order refer to that type, instead of referring to the concrete types by each order type.

This may be easier said than done, depending on the similarities/differences of Task and Model. It may require refactoring and abstracting more stuff to work.

If that proves to be too many changes/work, fall back to the visitor pattern.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you add an abstract method `doCalculation` on your base class and then override it in your subclasses. When you iterate over your order list, you simply call the `doCalculation` method and process accordingly.

Comment: Because the calculation needs different lists/variables in the calculation class, based on whether the specific field is a model or a task... To be able to override, the calculation should use the same fields, so the fields can be passed as a parameter, right?